# Catastrophic backtracking error when using a regex pattern

Tags: php, regex, backtracking

My regex pattern is:

```
 (<span style="color:green">?(\s*|\w*|\S*)*<li>)(?! ?\s*<\/span>)
```

Whenever I am trying input as:

```
 <span style="color:green"> anything <li>
```

It works fine, but whenever the last condition occurs that is whenever li tag is followed by the closing span tag then it gives error:
Example whenever my input is:

```
<span style="color:green"> anything <li></span>
```

What is the actual problem in my pattern?
Instead of: (?! ?\s*</span>) I have also tried:

```
 ^(</span>)
```

but the same error occurs. I will be embedding it in PHP.

In short what I need to do is: Whenever li opening tag lies after span opening tag but span closing tag is not present just after li tag then I need to replace my li tag with something.

Comment: The proper answer is: use an HTML parser rather than regular expressions. Regex-based workarounds are certainly possible, but you can never rely on them when parsing arbitrary HTML.

Comment: In PHP, you can easily use DOMDocument and DOMXPath. Please post more sample data and specify what you need to extract from it.

Comment: @stribizhev My input would be: <span style="color:green"> Any words/tags/spaces in between <li> tag and  li closing tag should also be between span opening and closing tag and Output I want is both span opening and closing tag should be removed and li should be replaced by something I want

Answer (score 0):

Your catastrophic backtracking occurs because of `(...|\w*|\S*)*<`. Take `"an item"`. At position 0, the regexp needs to test all of these possibilities

```
<
()<
(\w)<
(\w\w)<
(\w\w\w)
()<
(\S)<
(\S\S)<
(\S\S\S)
()()<
()(\w)<
()(\w\w)<
()(\w\w\w)
()()<
()(\S)<
()(\S\S)<
()(\S\S\S)
(\w)()<
(\w)(\w)<
(\w)(\w\w)
(\w)()<
(\w)(\S)<
(\w)(\S\S)
(\w\w)()<
(\w\w)(\w)
(\w\w)()<
(\w\w)(\S)
(\w\w\w)()
(\w\w\w)()
()()<
()(\w)<
()(\w\w)<
()(\w\w\w)
()()<
()(\S)<
()(\S\S)<
()(\S\S\S)
(\S)()<
(\S)(\w)<
(\S)(\w\w)
(\S)()<
(\S)(\S)<
(\S)(\S\S)
(\S\S)()<
(\S\)(\w)<
(\S\S)()<
(\S\S)(\S)
(\S\S\S)()
(\S\S\S)()
()()()<
()()(\w)<
()()(\w\w)<
()()(\w\w\w)
()()()<
()()(\S)<
()()(\S\S)<
()()(\S\S\S)
()(\w)()<
()(\w)(\w)<
()(\w)(\w\w)
()(\w)()<
()(\w)(\S)<
()(\w)(\S\S)
()(\w\w)()<
()(\w\w)(\w)
()(\w\w)()<
()(\w\w)(\S)
()(\w\w\w)()
()()()<
()()(\w)<
()()(\w\w)<
()()(\w\w\w)
()()()<
()()(\S)<
()()(\S\S)<
()()(\S\S\S)
()(\S)()<
()(\S)(\w)<
()(\S)(\w\w)
()(\S)()<
()(\S)(\S)<
()(\S)(\S\S)
()(\S\S)()<
()(\S\)(\w)<
()(\S\S)()<
()(\S\S)(\S)
()(\S\S\S)()
(\w)()()<
(\w)()(\w)<
(\w)()(\w\w)
(\w)()()<
(\w)()(\S)<
(\w)()(\S\S)
(\w)(\w)()<
(\w)(\w)(\w)
(\w)(\w)()<
(\w)(\w)(\S)
(\w)(\w\w)()
(\w)(\w\w)()
(\w)()()<
(\w)()(\w)<
(\w)()(\w\w)
(\w)()()<
(\w)()(\S)<
(\w)()(\S\S)
(\w)(\S)()<
(\w)(\S)(\w)
(\w)(\S)()<
(\w)(\S)(\S)
(\w)(\S\S)()
(\w)(\S)(\w)
(\w)(\S\S)()
(\w\w)()()<
(\w\w)()(\w)
(\w\w)()()<
(\w\w)()(\S)
(\w\w)(\w)()
(\w\w)(\w)()
(\w\w)()()<
(\w\w)()(\w)
(\w\w)()()<
(\w\w)()(\S)<
(\w\w)(\S)()
(\w\w)(\S)()
(\w\w\w)()()
(\S)()()<
(\S)()(\w)<
(\S)()(\w\w)
(\S)()()<
(\S)()(\S)<
(\S)()(\S\S)
(\S)(\w)()<
(\S)(\w)(\w)
(\S)(\w)()<
(\S)(\w)(\S)
(\S)(\w\w)()
(\S)(\w\w)()
(\S)()()<
(\S)()(\w)<
(\S)()(\w\w)
(\S)()()<
(\S)()(\S)<
(\S)()(\S\S)
(\S)(\S)()<
(\S)(\S)(\w)
(\S)(\S)()<
(\S)(\S)(\S)
(\S)(\S\S)()
(\S)(\S)(\w)
(\S)(\S\S)()
(\S\S)()()<
(\S\S)()(\w)
(\S\S)()()<
(\S\S)()(\S)
(\S\S)(\w)()
(\S\S)(\w)()
(\S\S)()()<
(\S\S)()(\w)
(\S\S)()()<
(\S\S)()(\S)
(\S\S)(\S)()
(\S\S)(\S)()
(\S\S\S)()()
...
```

in order to eliminate `"an "` as a possible match. (I probably messed up somewhere, but you get the drift.)

Also note that `\s|\S` is `.` (except newlines). But what you really want is "not a start of tag": `[^<]*</li>`. This way, to eliminate `"an "` as a candidate, the regexp engine only needs to test these:

```
<
[^<]<
[^<][^<]<
```

(Also, +1 to stribizhev's comment: use a HTML processing library to process HTML.)

Comment: Any other tag could exist but not just span closing tag, that's why I defined it completely inside that bracket. Any starting tag would not work in this situation

Comment: I stripped down the regex to the bit that causes the problem (non-deterministic alternation `\S|\w` and the following character `<` that invalidates patterns and triggers backtracking); `li` is not a part of the problem.